# How do I generate the Correlation Coefficient of multiple columns of a dataframe as a new column variable in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. Here, I want to generate the Correlation Coefficient between the array [A1, A2] and array [B1, b2]. This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
A1  A2  B1  B2
1   5   7   6
3   3   4   5
6   4   5   7
2   7   6   8
5   9   1   3
```

I want to convert this into the following data frame:

```
A1  A2  B1  B2  Corr_Coeff
1   5   7   6   <Value 1>
3   3   4   5   <Value 2>
6   4   5   7   <Value 3>
2   7   6   8   <Value 4>
5   9   1   3   <Value 5>
```

Right now, I am splitting the dataframe into two seperate dataframes and trying a `df.T.corrwith` operation. However, even that returns null values.

Can anybody provide some guidance as to how to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you do the math and tell me what it is you want?

Comment: The values resulting would be:
-1
<Error Term>
-1
1
1

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the answers and seeing if they solved your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for row-wise Pearson correlation coefficients (note that this will be either +1 or -1 for two data points, and `NaN` if one or both of the coordinates does not change!):

```
a = ['A1', 'A2']
b = ['B1', 'B2']
df[a].corrwith(df[b].rename(columns={bi: ai for ai, bi in zip(a, b)}), 
               axis=1)
0   -1.0
1   NaN 
2   -1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```